# I keep on getting the error "java.util.InputMismatchException" in my code

Tags: java

I have been working on this code for a project and I keep getting the error "java.util.InputMismatchException". I have searched and found similar questions but I don't get how the answers apply to my code. I know that I'm entering the input correctly so that's out. Also, I have been trying to reformat my code, but it just seems to make it worse. I'm sorry if this is plainly obvious and I don't recognize it, I just started to code. Thanks for your patience.

Here's the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at songBottlesOfBeer.BottlesOfBeer.main(BottlesOfBeer.java:47)
```

Here's my full piece of code:

```
package songBottlesOfBeer;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BottlesOfBeer {

        private static Scanner bottles;
            public static void number(int n) {

                if (n>1) {
                    System.out.print(n+" bottles of beer on the wall, "+
                            n+" bottles of beer, ya' take one down, "+
                            "ya' pass it around, ");
                    n=n-1 ;
                    System.out.println(n+" bottles of beer on the wall.");
                    number(n);
                }else{

                    if(n==1) {
                        System.out.print(n+" bottle of beer on the wall, "+
                                n+" bottle of beer, ya' take one down, "+
                                "ya' pass it around, ");
                                n=n-1 ;
                        System.out.println(n +" bottles of beer on the wall.");
                        number(n);
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall, " +
                                "no bottles of beer, ya' can't take one down, "
                                + "ya' can't pass it around, 'cause there are"
                                + " no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
                            }

                        }
                }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                bottles = new Scanner(System.in);
                bottles.useDelimiter("\n");

                System.out.println("Enter the starting number of " 
                        + "bottles in the song "
                        + "'99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall':");
                number(bottles.nextInt());
                }
}
```

The error is located in number(bottles.nextInt());

Comment: The exception happens at `BottlesOfBeer.java:47`, which is which line?

Comment: @user1803551 I guess `number(bottles.nextInt());`

Comment: @GáborBakos Yes, but we shouldn't guess. The OP should know always to tell us where the error occurs in the code.

Comment: @user1803551 
I'm sorry for not telling where the error is located. The error is number(bottles.nextInt()); So yes GáborBakos, you were correct.

Comment: You should edit your question with this information (either add a comment to the line in the code or just mention it). This time it's obvious, but for the sake of other cases, make this a habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
bottles.useDelimiter("\n");
```

First of all avoid using `\n` as a line separator since it is OS dependent. Use `System.lineSeparator()` or a `\R` if in a regex. Secondly, the delimiter is used to tokenize (break) a *single* input into several parts, which is not what you need. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> automatically submits a single input.

**Example**

```
    Scanner bottles = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(bottles.nextInt());
    System.out.println(bottles.nextInt());
    System.out.println(bottles.nextInt());
```

The first call will block the execution waiting for input. The input is tokenized by the default delimiter which is `\p{javaWhitespace}+` (basically white-spaces). Let's look at the following cases:

Input: `1 2 3` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

This happens because the single 5 character input was tokenized into 3 segments, which where then called sequentially by the `nextInt` methods.

Input `1 2` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Output:

```
1
2
//cursor mark
```

This happens because you "saturated" the first 2 calls to `nextInt`, but the 3rd did not find another integer, and so it prompts the user for input (and blocks execution).

Input: `1 2 3 4` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

As in the first case, only now the scanner stores the input `4` and the next call will utilize it.

*Remember to close the scanner when you finish*:

```
bottles.close();
```

Comment: I don't really get what I have to change. So since bottles.useDelimiter("\n"); isn't what I need do I change it to 
bottles.System.lineSeparator(); ? 
Thanks for telling me about the closing of the scanner, I did get a error message(previously) about this.

Comment: @dragonbunnies The first 2 lines in my answer is what you have to change.

Answer (score 1):

I tryed your code and it works perfectly..

This exception simply means that you have entered something (I have no clue what) but it was not an `Integer` which is what is supposed to be read.

Here is the output I get when writing 5 :

> Enter the starting number of bottles in the song '99 Bottles of Beer
>   on the Wall': 5 5 bottles of beer on the wall, 5 bottles of beer, ya'
>   take one down, ya' pass it around, 4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4
>   bottles of beer on the wall, 4 bottles of beer, ya' take one down, ya'
>   pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer on
>   the wall, 3 bottles of beer, ya' take one down, ya' pass it around, 2
>   bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles
>   of beer, ya' take one down, ya' pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on
>   the wall. 1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer, ya' take one
>   down, ya' pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall. No more
>   bottles of beer on the wall, no bottles of beer, ya' can't take one
>   down, ya' can't pass it around, 'cause there are no more bottles of
>   beer on the wall!

Comment: I bet OP is throwing a space in with the input

Comment: @drewmoore I'm not adding a space to it.
I tried it again and got the error message. I've been using this
http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner.html 
, it is showing the right way to enter an input right?

Comment: @dragonbunnies I think he is using Unix where `\n` is the "correct" line delimiter. If you are on Windows and change in your code to `\n\r` it should also somewhat work.